# What does -> mean?

Tags: objective-c

I'm a relative newbie to Objective-C (only studied Arron Hillegras's book) and am confused by the following snippit of code I've found in one of Apple's code examples, in particular what does the -> mean?

```
-(id) initWithNumbers:(NSArray *)numbers
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    { 
       self->_numbers = [numbers copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In the header file _numbers is declared as

```
NSNumber * _number;
```

( the underscore has some significance from what I recall reading somewhere but that too eludes me at the moment.

Thanks
Robin

Answer (score 8):

`->` is a normal C operator for accessing the members of a *pointer* to a struct; the `.` operator is for accessing members of a struct. Thus:

```
a->b
```

is translated to

```
(*a).b
```

Since Objective-C objects are pointers to structs underneath it all, this works for accessing instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

It's usually called the 'arrow' operator.  It allows you to access the instance variables of an object (or of a `struct`) using a reference or pointer to the instance.  It's common syntax with C and C++.

I'm struggling to find a nice write up, but you might find [this one](http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/04/objective-c-tuesdays-instance-variables.html) informative.

As to the underscore -  commonly they mean "private"; according to the [*Coding Guidelines for Cocoa - Naming Basics*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html):

> Avoid the use of the underscore
>   character as a prefix meaning private,
>   especially in methods. Apple reserves
>   the use of this convention. Use by
>   third parties could result in
>   name-space collisions; they might
>   unwittingly override an existing
>   private method with one of their own,
>   with disastrous consequences.

Comment: Thank you very much - the links were helpful and I think I've got this concept unscrambled now.

Answer (score 2):

You use `->` when you want to access an ivar. Like C structures you will use a `.` or `->` (in pointers to structs) in Objective-C objects you can use `->` but is not necessary since you can access them directly.

Hence:

```
self->_numbers = [numbers copy];
```

and

```
_numbers = [numbers copy];
```

are the same

You want to use `->` when you want to access that ivar explicitly.

Be aware that in Objective-C you can use `.` but only when its a property.
You can use `->` regardless that.

Answer (score 0):

That indicates a reference to -in this case- an instance variable of an object. `Self` refers to the object itself, and by writing `self->_numbers`, you refer to the variable that is part of the class instead of a global variable named `_numbers`.

Are you sure this is not mentioned in your book?

Comment: Yes it could be but I could not find it. And the index didn't help (:-)

Answer (score 0):

It's an operator which roots from C Programming Language.  And since Objective-C is compatible with C programming, you may see developers using traditional C-style programming.

"->" is used to access a elements of a pointer. And since the "objects" in Objective-C are just pointers (denoted by *), e.g. NSNumber *number; , you can use this notation to access their elements.

I never used this notation in Objective-C since the dot notation in Objective-C is accepted.  If "self" has a synthesized property "number" then self.number should be the same as self->number (this is true ONLY in Objective-C.